# Sending a .wav file using MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: iphone, email, audio, core-audio, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have a .wav file on the iPhone device that I would like to attach automatically to an email that people send from within my app. How would I do this?

Comment: what could be size of .wav file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could attach a file in mail by using the `addAttachmentData` method of `MFMailComposeViewController` class.

```
- (void)addAttachmentData:(NSData*)attachment mimeType:(NSString*)mimeType fileName:(NSString*)filename
```

Try with using the below statement.

```
[controller addAttachmentData:myWavData mimeType:@"audio/x-wav" fileName:@"myfile.wav"];
```